# Protecting Processing.js source

Tags: javascript, processing.js

Is there anyway to protect Processing.js sketch?

My company has a sketch that he wants to show to the world and in the mean time, he wants to ensure that no one can see his source code.

I've done protecting (partially) my javascript from browsers but the problem that I'm facing now is that firebug could reveal (XHR) my partially, protected source code.

So, I was wondering if I could obfuscate my source code. But would doing that cause processing.js to stop interpreting my source?

Is there anyway that I can use to protect my sketches?

Comment: What does it have with Java in common???

Comment: @maaartinus : Your Processing source stays the same. But instead of embedding Jar files, you're inserting Processing code to HTML pages and have Processing.js interpret it and draws the sketch.

Answer (score 2):

No, obfuscation won't break your source code. Everything should work fine, just like when using normal source code.

Have you thought about doing it some other way? For example, after making a sketch, why not convert it to SVG or some other image format and show that instead to the world?

Comment: That's strange. I had tried obfuscating my source code. But after doing so, Processing.js library could not interpret my Processing source anymore. Have never thought about using SVG but does SVG support some 3d lines and stuff? I'm new to SVG.

Answer (score 1):

File a bug with us on dealing with your obfuscated code, it should parse fine:

http://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284-processingjs/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the sketch data on the server and upload it via ajax, sending most of the processed result directly to the browser. But there will always be some readable code.

It's not in javascript nature to be hide itself.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I have done, so far. And with a few header + XHR tricks, I was able to hide the source code from plain browser view (view-source). However, since Firebug traces all XHR requests, my source code is totally exposed. I guess, this is quite impossible, after all.